# c++ Getting non syntax use "&" to create a pointer

Tags: c++, function, mp3

I have been working on my code and cannot seem to get this error fixed its the c_str': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member im not sure what im doing wrong.

```
 HSAMPLE sample = BASS_SampleLoad(FALSE, fi.Recv_Song().c_str, 0, 0, 1, BASS_SAMPLE_MONO);
```

I get the error from the fi.Recv_song.c_str variable its suppose to be a string for a file location so the the function its in can play a mp3 file from that location. ps. the recv funtion is one i made in a header file.

```
string &Get_Song()
{
    cin >> song;                  //this is the header file it is in.
    mpc = path + song;
     return mpc;
}
string Recv_Song()
{
    return mpc;
}
```

Comment: `c_str` is a function, not a variable. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: thats the thing causing the errors it seems that was the error code given

Comment: Yes, that's the thing causing the errors. You need to call the function, just like you do with `Recv_Song`.

Comment: Just wondering - why do you return the string (mpc) once by reference, then by value? And if you return by reference, consider returning a const reference - otherwise, a user might modify the string in a way not suitable for the implementation...

Comment: Poor error message - the compiler should consider both adding `()` and `&`` before making a suggestion. It's almost certain that only one of the two makes the code compile.

Answer (score 2):

Change line:

`HSAMPLE sample = BASS_SampleLoad(FALSE, fi.Recv_Song().c_str, 0, 0, 1, BASS_SAMPLE_MONO);`

to

`HSAMPLE sample = BASS_SampleLoad(FALSE, fi.Recv_Song().c_str(), 0, 0, 1, BASS_SAMPLE_MONO);`

c_str() is a function and you must call it as one.